# Server is listening in Port 110 and I can't find any way to disable or block it

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, port-scanning

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server used as web server, with ports for web (80, 443, and 8080) open for public sites hosted on it. Doing some security checks on it, I found it's listening on port 110 too:

> [image]

However, there is no POP3 service, or any mail service, running on that server.

It has both node.js and IIS installed, in case it's relevant.

The weird part is that port 110 is not listed when running `netstat -na` on the server, and it can't find anything listening on that port:

> [image]

I even added inbound/outbound rules to block port 110 on the server in the Firewall. Still no effect.

I can even connect with telnet to that port and send data, though the display is weird:

> [image]

Why and how is this port open? How to block it?

Comment: Any more luck with an added `-q` switch? Or resource monitor if you want a GUI.

Comment: @Lenniey thanks, but "-q" for what? For PortQry it just makes it quiet, and no such switch for netstat, so I am not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Hm...on my Windows 2012R2 servers I can use `netstat -q` to _Display all connections, listening ports, and [...]_. Have a look at the resource monitor then, especially the network tab or [tcpview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) from the [sysinternals suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/).

Comment: @Lenniey weird, probably something you installed, no -q switch for me. Checked in Resource Monitor, no port 110 listed in the network tab anywhere

Comment: Can you telnet into port 110 on said server?

Comment: @Lenniey yes! Thanks for the heads up... edited the question with the details.

Comment: If you correctly set a BLOCK rule on the server in Windows firewall and you don't see anything in the resource manager on the server, I'd suggest you don't even telnet into _that_ server. Last test would be to open wireshark or netmon or whatever, filter for port 110 and _then_ telnet into port 110 on the server to see if the traffic really ends there, or if it is intercepted somewhere on the way.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, the telnet is done from the server locally ? Just want to be sure its not a router service that remotly answer you.

Comment: @yagmoth555 not locally on the server, from my own machine. (both the telnet and PortQry.)

Comment: Well, I suspect you won't get any traffic on your server, then...I'd trace the traffic and portscan every hop to see where the potential hijack/intercept takes place (if you can see it at all). Is this "your" network?

Comment: @Lenniey not sure I understand the last comment, sorry. The server is dedicated (we installed everything) and hosted, the host gave us (the company I work for) full access via RDP, and assigned a public IP address to the server, to which anyone can also connect to see the site hosted on it. The site works, and with SSL as well, no problems with that. (I checked for open ports as part of security check we were asked to perform)

Comment: Well, then supposedly your company either has some network/service flaw somewhere or intercepts port 110 traffic whyever. Could you ask them? I'd also suggest to try out some external scanner, like https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2 to check your server for vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Lenniey now that you mention it, we do have a router provided by the ISP, through which we get Internet access.... so yeah likely the router itself is listening on port 110. How can I verify this for sure?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the router, just something along the path. Like I said: from your own PC run a `tracert -d <your server>`, then check every hop for the opened 110 port with a telnet call. But don't be surprised if you don't get an answer, because if you don't manage the complete network, literally _anything_ can happen to your traffic.

Comment: @Lenniey thanks! Confirmed this to be the "S-Box Security Internet Firewall" we have in the office, i.e. it has port 110 listening. Guess that's about it, can you please post answer with everything you said? (Which is relevant.. :))

Comment: just a note, some router do spam check and RBL check on email and/or gateway antivirus product that scan what come by it. If your network dont use POP3 at all I suggest to desactivate that, it open a possible security hole in the router.

Comment: @yagmoth555 yeah, I already asked the network admin to contact the ISP and request closing the port. (They own and operate the s-box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed to be a "S-Box Security Internet Firewall" by tracing the traffic and connecting to every hop IP using telnet on port 110. All traffic on port 110 passing this device seems to be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have firewall in between your workplace (where you were running scan) and your server.
The simplest check would be to try connecting to said port for the machine itself:

```
telnet 123.123.123.123 110
```

If it doesn't connect, you are most likely OK.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scFrg.png yeah, it doesn't work on the server itself, but still not sure there's no risk. How can firewall "listen" on a port though? And why 110 of all ports?

Comment: Try to check if port is open from another place.
Some firewalls may have some services and such running on random ports (F.E., your local sysadmin decided to block this port in your office. Software that he uses to do so behaves in a way, that it accepts connections on port and filters it).

Comment: 110 isn't just random port, it should be used only by POP3 service which makes this whole thing weird.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not open on the local host itself, so your weird output is definitely something else intercepting the connection attempt. Go find whoever is responsible for IT security where you work and they can probably tell you what it is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, already found, see comments under question.