# Unable to block port 25 on server

Tags: iptables, firewall, smtp

When I scan my server using nmap `$ sudo nmap -sS IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR`, I see a line with `25/tcp    open  smtp`. This is despite the fact that I'm not running postfix, exim or any other kind of mail server on the machine.

I have also tried to block port 25, using IP table rules.

`$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j DROP`

But despite running this and verifying that the iptable rule exists with `$ sudo iptables -L -n -v` running nmap still shows the port as being open.

I have also run `$ netstat -tulnp` on the server to see what ports are open, and port 25 does not show up in the list there.

Very confused on how to proceed, any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Output of `sudo iptables -nvL` - https://pastebin.com/5W9V2rrz

Output of `sudo iptables -t nat -nvL` - https://pastebin.com/v9ST06uz

Comment: Can you share a little more info on your setup? From where are you scanning with `nmap`? Is `IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR` a public IP configured _on_ your server or any kind of load-balancer, firewall with port mapping, etc. and your server is behind it?

Comment: @MrShunz i'm running nmap from my laptop at home. IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR is a public IP, and there are no firewalls or load-balancers that the server is behind. The only firewalls are the iptables running on the machine

Comment: It could be that something en route to your server is redirecting SMTP traffic, does your ISP allow direct SMTP access towards the internet? What banner is shown if you connect via telnet?

Comment: @wurtel when i connect with `telnet IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR 25` i see the following `Trying IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR \n Connected to mydomain.com \n Escape character is '^]'`. Are you talking about my ISP that i'm connecting to the internet from home, or the hosting service that is hosting the machine? As far as I know my ISP does allow direct access to SMTP, because i'm able to telnet to my server on port 25.

Comment: Sniff the traffic on your server for port 25, if you set your iptables rule correctly, I bet nothing will be there. Then for example check the hops via traceroute and try every hop for port 25 from 'top' to 'bottom'.

Comment: Check this related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/926650/server-is-listening-in-port-110-and-i-cant-find-any-way-to-disable-or-block-it#comment1200690_926650

Comment: @Lenniey ran `sudo tcptraceroute -p 25 IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR` and got responses back from all the hops in the middle and the last line read `14 mydomain.com (IP.ADDR.OF.SRVR) [open] 150ms 150ms 150ms`

Comment: `tcptraceroute -p` (usually) sets the source port of your connections: _When using the tcptraceroute wrapper, -p specifies the source port._ And please edit in your output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL`

Comment: Ran `sudo tcptraceroute IP.ADDR 25` and got 4 hops, with it showing [open] on the last one which is the server.

Comment: @arunkumar After connecting to port 25 you should get a line starting with "220". Try it with your ISP's SMTP server; you may need to wait a minute. If no 220 line, then there's no SMTP server listening, some other process is listening. Also try stopping all your docker services.

Comment: This is probably docker's "fault". If you're not careful, it changes your iptables completely to its liking. If you flush _all_ your chains etc. you can try it again, but be **very careful** as to not shut you out of the system.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the the ordering of your rule is incorrect. Try and move the rule further up, also what version of Linux are you running? If in Ubuntu try `#> lsof -i -n -P | grep :25` and see what program is being used to listen on that port and then change/stop that process

Comment: the output of the lsof command is blank, which is the same as the the output of netstat, showing nothing running on port 25.

Comment: Try `sudo fuser 25/tcp`

Comment: @wurtel i got a number of lines with this - `Cannot stat file /proc/9999/fd/9: Stale file handle` but nothing else.

Comment: @arunkumar OK, so nothing is actually listening to port 25. Although if you have virtual machines or containers (docker, lxc) those may be listening indirectly (iptables nat rules)...

Comment: @wurtel i'm running docker, there was one container which provided postfix-relay services, but it wasn't exposed to the host port. (Only provided SMTP to other containers). I tried turning that docker container off as well, but I'm still able to telnet to port 25 on the server

Comment: So from the iptables output at https://pastebin.com/5W9V2rrz I see that your drop rule is actually dropping those packets so that's ok, however there has to be something listening for that traffic (most likely indirectly, I believe @wurtel is correct here, you should investigate your container config) in order for the port to be advertised.